# Broadcom BCM43142 802.11b/g/n Wireless Driver isn't Working

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I have a big problem.

I have just installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my computer (or laptop or notebook). But, the wireless driver isn't working. I have checked the settings, but there is no menu named "Wi-Fi".

Notebook model: Acer Aspire E 11

This is the complete report:

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

$ rfkill list all
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

$ sudo apt search bcmwl-kernel-source
[sudo] password for juan:
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source/now 6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,local]
  Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA Wireless driver source

$ uname -r
5.0.0-13-generic

$ sudo modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/module/5.0.0-13-generic
```

### EDIT:

After I reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source. It's most done. But, I get this following message:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': operation not permitted
```

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl` I suspect Secure Boot.

Comment: modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/module/5.0.0-13-generic

Comment: It appears that the correct driver isn't yet installed. With a temporary working internet connection: `sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` You will need to disable Secure Boot if it is present on your BIOS/EFI.

Answer (score 3):

OK, after I follow the last instruction of @chili555. I try to disable Secure Boot, and finally, my wireless driver is working.